# Only part of an image is being saved instead of the whole one, what should i fix?

Tags: java, client-server

Just wrote a client-server program in java.
For now, all the program does: client sends a screenshot, comprass the image, sends it to the server, the server saves the image in a directory.

For some reason, the image saved by the server is partial, meaning that not all the screenshot is saved in the server side.

**The screenshot at the client side:**

[image: here is the image saved in the server side]

**The relevant code:**

```
private static void screenshot(){

    try {

        BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
        File compressedImageFile = new File("C:\\Gilad\\Screenshots\\compress.jpg");
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(compressedImageFile);


        Iterator<ImageWriter> writers =  ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");
        ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) writers.next();

        ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(os);
        writer.setOutput(ios);

        ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();

        param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
        param.setCompressionQuality(1f);
        writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);

        os.close();
        ios.close();
        writer.dispose();

        Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Images\\Screenshots\\compress.jpg");

        byte[] compressedImage = Files.readAllBytes(path);
        serverThread.sendOutput(compressedImage);   //serverThread is object of type ThreadForServer

    } catch (HeadlessException | AWTException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Sending the image from ThreadForServer class:

```
outputThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            byte[] imageAr;
            //ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int len;
            byte[] lenAr;
            try{
                while(true){
                    if(outputs.isEmpty()) Thread.sleep(10);
                    else{
                        imageAr = outputs.remove();
                        len = imageAr.length;
                        System.out.println("length: " + len);
                        lenAr = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(len).array();
                        System.out.println("length array: " + lenAr + " " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                        socketOutput.write(lenAr);
                        System.out.println("Image array: " + imageAr + " " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                        socketOutput.write(imageAr);
                        socketOutput.flush();
                        System.out.println("Flushed: " + System.currentTimeMillis());

                    }
                }
            }catch(InterruptedException | IOException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }

        }

    });
```

InputThread in the server side:

```
    inputThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            byte[] imageAr;
            byte[] lenAr = new byte[4];
            int len;

            try{
                while(running){
                    System.out.println("Server input thread: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                    socketInput.read(lenAr);
                    len = ByteBuffer.wrap(lenAr).asIntBuffer().get();
                    System.out.println("length: " + len);
                    imageAr = new byte[len];
                    socketInput.read(imageAr);

                    inputs.add(imageAr);
                    break;

                }
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Server saving the image:

```
private static void startClientThreadHandler(ThreadForClient clientThread){
    new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                while(true){
                    byte[] image = clientThread.getInput();
                    if(image == null){
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                        continue;
                    }

                    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(image);
                    BufferedImage buffImage = ImageIO.read(in);

                    ImageIO.write(buffImage, "jpg", new File(IMAGE_DESTINATION + "\\image" + counter));
                    ++counter;

                }
            }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of potential issues here. The most likely, however, is when reading from the socket input:

```
                imageAr = new byte[len];
                socketInput.read(imageAr);
```

`InputStream.read(byte[])` does not guarantee to fill the provided `byte[]`. Instead, it returns how many bytes were read. It may require calling read multiple times to read all of the bytes.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read-byte:A-

Comment: @MuffinsDev, if this was indeed your issue, then consider marking this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's too much code and not enough code at the same time.

First isolate the  problem. Check if it's on the client side (are images captured correctly?), during transfer from the client (have you sent all the bytes?) or on the server (have you received all the bytes)?

My bet would be that when you do `socketInput.read(imageAr)` on the server side, you don't get all the data, only part of it. You have to read repeatedly until you get `-1`.

Comment: In this case, read until -1 or `len` bytes have been read. The client side is not closing the socket after sending the image, so in normal workflow, the server side should not receive a -1.